# Thunderbird 3.0 - how to prevent new message indicator from clearing?

Tags: thunderbird

I just installed Thunderbird 3.0 and there are a few things driving me batty.

When new email is delivered it has a faint star to the left of the subject (this is different than the new star column thing). In the old days (i.e. last week) the new message indicator wouldn't go away until I read the message or left the folder and returned. Now, as soon as I do anything with any email message, all new message indicators are cleared.

How can I go back to the old behavior?

Comment: I believe Thunderbird just confuses "new" and "unread". I think the "new" flag should be reset once you have seen the messages in the folder view (without opening) or clicked on the notification popup. Then it should be just "unread" until opened.

Answer (score 0):

To get old behaviour of message reading in Thunderbird 3.0 try :

[Compact Header Addon](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ghacks.net%2F2009%2F09%2F28%2Fswitch-to-compact-headers-in-thunderbird-3%2F&ei=5n9AS5D7OcrK_gatiqnAAQ&usg=AFQjCNHZ1tj9VXDj2EFr7NHtbNDxlJ_eyw&sig2=SNafRwUWXjCU3UN438DDew)

Comment: I don't understand why that would help in my case.  I tried it, mind you, but it didn't help at all.  Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: I added this because you wrote about old behaviours in thunderbird 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (2020) the problem is the other way around. The new indicator can only be cleared by either reading the message, manually getting mail or going to another folder. But "new" is not the same as "unread" so I use the following Autohotkey script to remove the "new" status whenever I tab away from the Thunderbird window.

How it works: When the Thunderbird window becomes "NotActive" then the shortcut {F5} is send to the Window, which triggers "Get New Messages for Current Account", which in turn resets the "new" status.

```
#
# Thunderbird Reset New on Inactive
#
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx

#Persistent 
SetTimer, MsgBoxCheck, 500

MsgBoxCheck:
{
  IfWinActive, Mozilla Thunderbird
  {
    WinWaitNotActive, Mozilla Thunderbird
    ControlSend, , {F5}, Mozilla Thunderbird
  }

  SetTimer, MsgBoxCheck, 500
}
```